# How send request every 2 seconds with Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have worker that send request to server and checks exist file.
Now worker runs at the specified time:

`CheckFileWorker.perform_in(@target_file.check_start_date, @target_file.url)`

1. I want run worker every 2 second. How I can do it?
2. May be need second Worker who will starting first Worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Sidetiq for scheduling recurring background jobs (https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq).

Basically you should do something similar to this:

```
class LicenseCheckerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence { hourly }

  def perform
    #your logic here
  end
end
```

Of course you should change the recurrence schedule to reflect your preferences.

Edit: another way to do this is schedule another run at the end of the #perform logic, delayed by 2 seconds.

Comment: something like recurrence { secondly(2) } should work

Comment: good gem, but now have problems with access to activerecord (with sidetiq): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454317/uninitialized-constant-in-worker